# Use VBA to reset Master-Child link for subform in Access

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

I am not sure what the optimal solution for what i am trying to do is so before i ask the technical question which I think is the most reasonable route to solve my problem, let me explain exactly what I want to do and get your suggestions.

Basically, I have built a multi-level switchboard-type form with the following three forms embedded:

Form A: The Master form in single mode showing 1 record at a time.
Form B: A subform in continous mode showing a set of sub records linked directly to the 1 record visualised in Form A.
Form C: a continuous subform showing a third level of sub records which could (if desired) be linked to the sub records in form B or could also be linked directly to the single record in Form A.

My requirement is that the records shown in form C can be linked directly the the records visualised in Form B, OR perhaps with a oggle with a button or option box, the link to Form B could be temporarily broken to allow for the records to be linked to the master single record displayed in Form A.

Basically, i want to user to have the option to view ALL 3rd level records belonging to the 1 record in Form A, or the option to use the level 2 sub records in form B to help filter the sub records in form C.

My beginner instincts to VBA programming tell me that perhaps I can write some code to allow for the links in Form C to be conncected to Form B or Connected to Form A depending on the user's preference but have no clue if this is possible.   It also occurred to me that this may also be resolvable by applying some industrial-strenght filters but I am having trouble understanding how to capture the correct that will allow for the filters to work.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it! Quite simple:

```
Me!frmProjectSubPhase09.LinkChildFields = "ID_Project_Phase"
Me!frmProjectSubPhase09.LinkMasterFields = "ID_Project_Phase"
```